Nestjs - signoz self-hosted(no logs)
i trying to use signoz self-hosted (docker) to log traces in my nestjs application, my code ahows no errors but i still do not see any logs , traces in the signoz ui
// tracer.ts
'use strict';

import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import { formattedLogger } from './utils/formatedLogger';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NodeSDK } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';

const logger = formattedLogger('Signoz');
 telemetry data to SigNoz
const exporterOptions = {
  url: 'http://server-ip:4318/v1/traces',
};

const traceExporter = new OTLPTraceExporter(exporterOptions);
const sdk = new NodeSDK({
  traceExporter,
  instrumentations: [
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations({
      '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-nestjs-core': { enabled: true },
    }),
  ],
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'imcoder-backend',
  }),
});

sdk.start();

// Gracefully shut down the SDK on process exit
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  sdk
    .shutdown()
    .then(() => logger.log('Tracing terminated'))
    .catch((error) => logger.error('Error terminating tracing: ' + error))
    .finally(() => process.exit(0));
});
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  sdk
    .shutdown()
    .then(() => logger.log('Tracing terminated'))
    .catch((error) => logger.error('Error terminating tracing:' + error))
    .finally(() => process.exit(0));
});
export default sdk;

Then im calling tracer in my main file:
// main.ts
...
tracer.start()
...

Can you try following this guide for setting up nextJS open telemetry
( https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/open-telemetry#manual-opentelemetry-configuration )
Create the instrument.ts and instrument.node.ts to take care of the edge cases where we only want it in node env.
also do set experimental.instrumentationHook = true; in your nextjS config which turns on the experimental feature. Then you need not to manually take care of importing the tracing.js file.
Thanks! Please do let me know if this works out.

Thanks for your answer @vikrant, but im on NestJS (backend)
